# socket is closed when trying to connect to port forwarded database

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I did the port forwarding to port `54320`

```
ssh -L 54320:<some host>:5432 ns1
```

I have the connection string that looks like this

```
postgres://<login>:<password>@localhost:54320/db_name
```

And I am trying to connect to `node-postgres` library like this

```
    const { Client } = require('pg');
    client = new Client({ connectionString: pgConnectionString });
    await client.connect(err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error('connection error', err.stack)
        } else {
            console.log('connected')
        }
    });
```

However it fails with `connection error Error [ERR_SOCKET_CLOSED]: Socket is closed`

What is the problem? `pg` version is  `"pg": "^7.11.0",`

Comment: Can you connect using `psql`?

Comment: yes, I can do that using dbeaver and psql

Comment: Shouldn't `localhost` be `ns1`?

Comment: ns1 is a host name in ssh config. It worked with localhost for everything except node-postgres for some reason

Comment: If you use `ns1` instead of `localhost` does in work with `node-postgres`?  Trying to determine whether this is name resolution issue.

Comment: Do not use both `await` and pass a callback. Use either.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver no it doesn't work with ns either. also I don't think that name resolution is the issue considering that I connect directly `psql postgres://<login>:<password>@localhost:54320/db_name` from terminal. Maybe I should try using POOL

Comment: @Bergi oh, I see